# Iphone Chrome Iframe Can Not Pass Third Party Cookie

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, iframe, third-party-cookies

I am facing a strange issue in Chrome iframe cookie pass.
domain A: https://a.com
domain B: https://b.com
A contains an iframe on domain B

when I access https://a.com, it will trigger iframe url,eg:https://b.com/endpoint/b,this url will return some B domain's cookie, but when trigger another B domain url: https://b.com/endpoint/c,  it does't pass any B domain's cookie.

if I access B domain first, than do above steps, it can pass B domain's cookie success.

this isuse only occurs in iphone's chrome(version:120.0.6099.119, IOS:17.1.2) browser.
iphone already enabled:settings->chrome-> enable third party cookies

I couldn't find any similar questions on the Internet ，Has anyone encountered the same problem?

the expect behavior is : the B domain's cookie can be passed successful. but in my testing, B domain's cookie are missing. and it only in iphone chrome browser.